# Flattening 2D grid of 2D arrays into a single 2D array, in JavaScript (functionally?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, functional-programming, flatten

I have a 2D array (grid) of 2D arrays (chunks) for a game I'm developing:

```js
const c1 = [[1, 2],
            [3, 4]]

const c2 = [[5, 6],
            [7, 8]]

const c3 = [[9, 0],
            [1, 2]]

const c4 = [[3, 4],
            [5, 6]]

const grid_of_chunks = [[c1, c2],
                        [c3, c4]];
```

and I want to reduce/flatten the `grid_of_chunks` to:

```js
[[1, 2, 5, 6],
 [3, 4, 7, 8],
 [9, 0, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 5, 6]]
```

I've been able to implement a functional solution for this (in 2 lines of Clojure), but I'm struggling to wrap my head around translating it to functional JavaScript, and bridging the gap between the two language's `map` semantics (JS map only accepts one array, whereas Clojure's `map` accepts many collections...).

This is as far as I got:

```js
function join_grid_of_chunks(gofc) {
    const joined_horiz = gofc.map(
        gofc_row => [].map.apply(gofc_row, [cs => [].concat.apply(cs)])
    );
    return [].concat.apply(joined_horiz);
}
```

Edit: Clojure solution (which works for uniformly-sized square chunks, in an arbitrarily sized square grid):

```clj
(defn join-grid-of-chunks [gofc]
  (let [joined (map #(apply map concat %) gofc)]
    (apply concat joined)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general solution using `flatMap` is to map over the indices from the first chunk of each grid row.

```
function joinGridOfChunks(grid) {
    return grid.flatMap(row => row[0].map((_, i) => row.flatMap(chunk => chunk[i])))
}
```

With a `zip` function (such as the one in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zip)), you could write it slightly more elegantly as:

```
function zip(...arrays) {
    return arrays[0].map((_, i) => arrays.map(arr => arr[i]))
}
function joinChunks(chunks) { // Horizontally join an array of chunks e.g. [[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]] --> [[1,2,5,6],[3,4,7,8]]
    return zip(...chunks).map(row => row.flat())
}
console.log(gridOfChunks.flatMap(joinChunks));
```

`zip` plus `map` seems to be close to Clojure's `map` with multiple collections. This should work for any shape 2d chunks in a 2d grid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have:

```js
const c1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
const c2 = [[5, 6], [7, 8]];
const c3 = [[9, 0], [1, 2]];
const c4 = [[3, 4], [5, 6]];

const grid_of_chunks = [
  [c1, c2],
  [c3, c4]
];

function transform(input) {
  return input.flatMap(rows => {
    return rows.reduce((result, chunk) => {
      chunk.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
        result[rowIndex] = result[rowIndex] || [];
        result[rowIndex].push(...row);
      });
      return result;
    }, []);
  });
}

console.log(transform(grid_of_chunks));
```

Should work for NxN chunks and MxM grid